# Mixture of categorical and numerical data pyplot

Tags: python

I am going through the Titanic example in Kaggle and I just wanted to ask about a Python thing - I've looked around for this, but I don't seem to find anything.

Say I have a DataFrame with columns that include numerical and categorical data. I am trying to create 3 subplots, each of displaying this data. Something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(20,20))
ax[0].hist(train_data['Age'])
ax[1].scatter(train_data.PassengerId,train_data.Cabin)
ax[2].scatter...
```

I don't have a problem of creating these plots separately, pyplot displays the strings in Cabin vs PassengerId numbers, but it just can't deal with plotting them on one figure. Even looping and creating new figures for each plot doesn't seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this how pyplot works? Does it "set" the type of the data at the first line of the code? Can I use some kind of .astype() method to workaround this?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that matplotlib "can't deal with plotting them on one figure" - what happens vs what do you expect? From your description it is likely you are doing something wrong, but the description is not sufficient enough to be able to tell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but plotting different things in different panels of a figure (or different things in the same panel) is something that can be easily done with matplotlib. See an example below using seborn's copy of titanic data (it also shows how to use seaborn to create statistical plots easily):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(8, 10))
ax[0].hist(titanic['age'])
ax[1].scatter(titanic.age, titanic.fare)
sns.pointplot(x='class', y='survived', data=titanic, hue='sex', axis=ax[2])
```

This is the image you should see (provided you have seaborn installed):
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. But I see that you're using sns. To plot the categorical data. My point was that your sns.pinplot() line was a[2].scatter() and that doesn't work. If I only plot categorical data, so say just use plt.plot() on one figure, that works.

Comment: By doesn't work you mean you get an error? If you want to scatterplot text data you should get an error because that is not well defined. For dealing with such categorical data using seaborn is a good solution - it actually uses matplotlib under the hood, but saves you some trouble.

Comment: You can see more examples of using seaborn here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html

Comment: Ok, so I have no idea what I did before because I can't recreate it. I 100% did not use sns, I only used plt. I created one figure where on y axis were the names of all the Cabin names and on x was passenger number.